# How to remove three lines in row if the first line contain some text? (AWK)

Tags: linux, awk, row

I have a txt file like this:

```
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# WR
ABABABABABABABABAB
BABABBABABABABABAA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
# SL
AAABABABABABABBABA
AAABBABABABABABABA
```

I would like to remove all the data that are for SL and WR (as example). So I will have only:

```
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
```

I know how to remove one line that start or contain something but no idea how to do with 3 lines in row.

This is what I use to remove lines that contain something:

```
awk ' $2 !~ /SL/ && $2 !~ /WR/ ' test.txt > test_new.txt
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to remove all the three lines together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure `awk` solution using a print flag (inspired by [**dogbane**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7412/dogbane)):

```
$ awk '/^#/{p=1}/^# (SL|WR)/,/^#/{p=0}p' file
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
```

Explanation:

`/^#/ {p=1}` If the line starts with a `#` set the print flag `p` to `1`

`/^# (SL|WR)/,/^#/{p=0}` If the line is in the range starting `# SL` or `# WR` until the next line starting `#` set the print flag to `0`

`p` If the print flag is non-zero the default block is run `{print}` else `0` and nothing is printed.

The order is important here, first the print flag is turned on at every new record and only turned off for the records `SL` and `WR`.

---

Using `record seperators`:

You can redefine what a `record` is with `awk` by setting the `RS` variable. By default each record is separated by a newline but for your example with can use `#` as the record seperator and only print the records where by the first field isn't `WR` or `SL`:

```
$ awk '$1 != "SL" && $1 != "WR"' RS=# ORS=# file
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
#
```

A small issue with this approach is the last record separator. A simple fix would be to pipe to `sed '$d'`:

```
$ awk '$1 != "SL" && $1 != "WR"' RS=# ORS=# file | sed '$d'
# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
```

Note: the variable `ORS` is the Output Record Separator we need to set this so the `#` is displayed in the output.

Comment: just to make sure `RS` define the begging of the line and `ORS` the end?

Comment: @mahmood sorry I did not explain what the variable `ORS` is, I have added a note explaining it. `awk` lets you specify both the `record separator` and `output record separator`.

Comment: If you're piping to `sed` you might as well use `sed` to do the whole thing, as in my answer.

Comment: @dogbane thanks for the inspiration, I have added a pure `awk` solution. I think the idea of record separators is still a good lesson to teach here but a print flag approach is probably simpler.

Comment: @sudo_O could you give a walk through of the pure awk solution please. I am unsure of the purpose of ,/^#/ in the p=0 flag and how this differs from the initial regex {p=1}

Comment: @moadeep I have added an explanation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

To delete `# WR`:

```
sed -e '/^# WR/,/^#/ {/^# WR/d;/^#/!d}' file
```

To delete both `# WR` and `# SL` blocks:

```
$ sed -e '/^# WR/,/^#/ {/^# WR/d;/^#/!d}' -e '/^# SL/,/^#/ {/^# SL/d;/^#/!d}' file

# RIR1
ABABABABABABABABAA
ABABABABABABABABBA
# BR2
ABABABABABABABBABA
ABBABABABABABABABA
```

Or, as suggested by sudo_O:

```
sed -r '/^# (WR|SL)/,/^#/ {/^# (WR|SL)/d;/^#/!d}' file
```

Comment: +1! You could use alteration here inside like `sed -r '/^# (WR|SL)/,/^#/ {/^# (WR|SL)/d;/^#/!d}'` especially if the number of records is greater than two!

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessing the file:

```
awk '/#/{print x}1' file | awk '$2!="SL" && $2 !="WR"' RS=
```